# Typescript exclude not working with baseUrl

Tags: typescript, emacs, tsc, flycheck

I am trying to exclude some files from my typescript compilation because my editor writes temporary files that are causing extraneous recompiles when making changes. I have in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"exclude": ["*flycheck*", "**/*flycheck*"]
```

I am using `tsc --watch` to watch for changes and compile.

This works, *until* I add a `baseUrl` to my config like so:

```
"baseUrl": "src",
```

I'm using `baseUrl` because I prefer absolute import paths over relative.

I have tried adjusting the exclude globs but cannot for the life of me get typescript to ignore these files when the `baseUrl` is set. Is there some reason that the file exclusions would not work with a `baseUrl`?

Comment: Can you provide a code example? Also use `tsc --listFiles` and `tsc --traceResolution` to check, [what and why](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-a-file-in-the-exclude-list-still-picked-up-by-the-compiler) files are included.

Comment: are those excluded directories within the base url?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an `include` in your tsconfig.json?

From the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude

> Exclude - exclude
>
> [...]
>
> It is not a mechanism that prevents a file from being included in the
> codebase - it simply changes what the include setting finds.

It means that it has no effect if `include` or `files` aren't present.